# Conjugate transpose operator ".H" in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, monkeypatching

It is very convenient in numpy to use the `.T` attribute to get a transposed version of an `ndarray`.  However, there is no similar way to get the conjugate transpose. Numpy's matrix class has the `.H` operator, but not ndarray.  Because I like readable code, and because I'm too lazy to always write `.conj().T`, I would like the `.H` property to always be available to me.  How can I add this feature? Is it possible to add it so that it is brainlessly available every time numpy is imported?

(A similar question could by asked about the `.I` inverse operator.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general, the difficulty in this problem is that Numpy is a C-extension, which cannot be monkey patched...or can it?  The [forbiddenfruit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forbiddenfruit) module allows one to do this, although it feels a little like playing with knives.

So here is what I've done:

1. Install the very simple [forbiddenfruit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forbiddenfruit) package
2. Determine the user customization directory:

   ```
   import site
   print site.getusersitepackages()
   ```
3. In that directory, edit `usercustomize.py` to include the following:

   ```
   from forbiddenfruit import curse
   from numpy import ndarray
   from numpy.linalg import inv
   curse(ndarray,'H',property(fget=lambda A: A.conj().T))
   curse(ndarray,'I',property(fget=lambda A: inv(A)))
   ```
4. Test it:

   ```
   python -c python -c "import numpy as np; A = np.array([[1,1j]]);  print A; print A.H"
   ```

   Results in:

   ```
   [[ 1.+0.j  0.+1.j]]
   [[ 1.-0.j]
    [ 0.-1.j]]
   ```

Answer (score 32):

You can subclass the `ndarray` object like:

```
from numpy import ndarray

class myarray(ndarray):    
    @property
    def H(self):
        return self.conj().T
```

such that:

```
a = np.random.rand(3, 3).view(myarray)
a.H
```

will give you the desired behavior.

### Edit:

As suggested by @slek120, you can force to transpose only the last 2 axes with:

```
self.swapaxes(-2, -1).conj()
```

instead of `self.conj().T`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for a monkey patching type solution where I could still use ndarray everywhere, e.g. `A = np.random.randn(3,3) + 1j*np.random.randn(3,3); B = A.H.dot(A)`

Comment: @benpro I see... but [this would be trickier](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#implications-for-subclassing)

Comment: I use `self.swapaxes(-2, -1).conj()` which only transposes the last 2 axes instead of all of them, which is useful for an array of matrices.

Comment: @slek120, good hint. I will refer to your comment in the main answer