# How to force "a+b" to always call "b.radd(a)" when a is numpy array, and b is my type?

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone see a good way to solve the issue in title? It comes up when `numpy` does something silly for addition to my custom data type (as [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2289)) and I want to override its behavior

I found [this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules) in official docs for coercion rules, which says that it could be done if "b"'s class is subclass of `numpy` array type, but it's suboptimal because I don't want my type to subclass `ndarray`

Comment: A minimal working example would be very helpful. Why don't you want to inherit from `ndarray`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`__array_priority__`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html#the-array-priority-attribute) attribute used by numpy to indicate your type has a higher priority. eg.

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:

    __array_priority__ = 0

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.arr = np.array(data)

    def __array__(self):
        return self.arr

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return "MyClass radd"

a = np.array([1])
b = MyClass([2])

# low priority (or no priority), numpy array addition
assert isinstance(a + b, np.ndarray)

# higher priority, your addition
MyClass.__array_priority__ = 1
assert a + b == "MyClass radd"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with monkey-patching, something like:

```
old_add = np.ndarray.__add__

def new_add(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, MyType):
        return other.__radd__(self)
    else:
        return old_add(self, other)

np.ndarray.__add__ = new_add
```

This will normally throw an error `can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'numpy.ndarray'`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26938248/2482744) there is a workaround, I'll let you try it out yourself.